# The type '<>f__AnonymousType13<'',''>' exists in both '' and 'EntityFramework.dll'

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I wrote a code for getting list in list with anonymous data type like below

```
var AvgPriceList = x.GroupBy(y => y.Retailer).Select(k => 
  new { Retailer = k.Key, 
        AvgUnitPrice = k.Sum(z => z.Units) == 0 ? 0 : (double)k.Sum(z => z.Dollars) / k.Sum(z => z.Units)
     }), 
    AvgUnitPrice = x.Sum(y => y.Units) == 0 ? 0 : (double)x.Sum(y => y.Dollars) / x.Sum(y => y.Units), 
    EDLP_Price = x.FirstOrDefault().EDLPPrice, Units = x.Sum(y => y.Units), USBEDLP = x.Sum(y => y.USBEDLP) });
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding extra property to the inner anonymus class like below

```
     AvgPriceList = x.GroupBy(y => y.Retailer).Select(k => 
                                                          new { Retailer = k.Key, 
                                                                AvgUnitPrice = k.Sum(z => z.Units) == 0 ? 0 : (double)k.Sum(z => z.Dollars) / k.Sum(z => z.Units),
                                                                AvgUnits = k.Sum(z => z.Units)
                                                             }), 
            AvgUnitPrice = x.Sum(y => y.Units) == 0 ? 0 : (double)x.Sum(y => y.Dollars) / x.Sum(y => y.Units), 
            EDLP_Price = x.FirstOrDefault().EDLPPrice, Units = x.Sum(y => y.Units), USBEDLP = x.Sum(y => y.USBEDLP) });
```